# refs not working in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a TextInput which I want to reference in my function.

```
next() {
        let body = this.refs.body.value
    }

<View>
    <Text>Place the body here</Text>
    <TextInput ref="body" placeholder="Your body goes here..." style={styles.body} placeholderTextColor='green'/>
</View>
```

But I am getting this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs.body')

Is `ref` not working in react-native?

Answer (score 9):

I think they have changed the way ref works. Now instead of a string, ref accepts a function that gets called when the particular component gets rendered.
You could try something like,

```
next() {
let body = this._textInput.value
}

<View>
    <Text>Place the body here</Text>
    <TextInput ref={component => this._textInput = component} placeholder="Your body goes here..." style={styles.body} placeholderTextColor='green'/>
</View>
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html

Or, you could also attach an onChange to your TextInput and record the input when the next button is clicked.

EDIT:
Ref still accepts string but it is to be deprecated. Use the function in ref instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to the fact that you refer to an element which is not mounted yet. Did you make sure to refer to it on `componentDidMount` or later?

Comment: Yes, I think so. After component renders, I can press the next button. Does this not mean I can press next after `componentDidMount`? I am sorry I very new.

Answer (score 0):

this is working good

if you want to see the attributes of ref just console.log(this._textInput) in
  onFoucus()
......

```
onFocus(){
  this._textInput.root.focus()
}
<textInput
  ref={component => this._textInput = component}
/>
```